# Query SPARQL in Java (Jena)

Tags: java, eclipse, sparql, jena

I'm starting to program in SPARQL and know the rdf world.
I would like to make a query that displays all idSensor and the value.
The code is as follows :

```
public class HelloRDF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//
//  //CONNESSIONE RDF METEO
//      final String uri = "http://www.dati.lombardia.it/resource/647i-nhxk/";
//      final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
//      model.read(uri);
//      model.write(System.out);


        String s2 = "PREFIX  rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n" +
                "PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
                "PREFIX  socrata: <http://www.socrata.com/rdf/terms#>\n" +
                "PREFIX  dcat: <http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#>\n" +
                "PREFIX  ods: <http://open-data-standards.github.com/2012/01/open-data-standards#>\n" +
                "PREFIX  dcterm: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>\n" +
                "PREFIX  geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>\n" +
                "PREFIX  skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>\n" +
                "PREFIX  foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>\n" +
                "PREFIX  dsbase: <http://www.dati.lombardia.it/resource/>\n" +
                "PREFIX  ds: <http://www.dati.lombardia.it/resource/647i-nhxk/>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "SELECT  ?idsensore ?valore \n" +
                "WHERE\n" +
                "  { ?x ds:idsensore ?idsensore .\n" +
                "?x ds:valore ?valore .\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "LIMIT   5\n" +
                "";

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(s2); //s2 = the query above
        QueryExecution qExe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService( "http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query );
        ResultSet results = qExe.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ;


    }

}
```

The table that returns the query is empty
where am I doing wrong?
Please help me.

Comment: what kind of problem do you get?

Comment: the table that returns the query is empty

Comment: The result you are getting is the expected one. You can check it out on your own if you run the query directly in the SPARQL endpoint available at: http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: In rdf there are a lot of idsensor and value.I don't understand why there are zero results.In what way i can display all result than storage in this resourse https://www.dati.lombardia.it/Ambiente/Dati-sensori-meteo/647i-nhxk ?

Comment: You are using the dbpedia endpoint. Is that right? If yes, your query returns 0 elements.

Comment: Do you have a SPARQL endpoint for your resource at dati.lombardia.it?

Comment: no i haven't endpoint

Comment: And why do you think that DBpedia contains the data that you want? DBpedia is based on Wikipedia. Does Wikipedia contain the data that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBpedia doesn't contain the data that you're looking for.  Perhaps some other endpoint does, but you'll need to run the query against an endpoint that has that data.

What you've done is essentially the same as writing a query for one company's database and expecting that it will return the same results when you run it on another company's database.

Comment: ok. so if I insert the RDF data in a local file, in what way i can change the query?

Comment: You don't have to change the query, but load the data into something that allows to run SPARQL queries on the data. Usually it's called a triple store. Some other frameworks support to load data into memory and run SPARQL on it, e.g. Jena and Sesame.

Answer (score -1):

QueryExecutionFactory takes the URL of a SPARQL endpoint. If you don't have one you cannot query your data using this approach:

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/QueryExecutionFactory.html#sparqlService-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: You can create a query execution for a local model.

Comment: In his example he is using a remote endpoint, that's the reason for my answer... In addition, you need the data to be available in a datastore supporting SPARQL. If this is not correct, please provide an example. Thanks!